# Ubuntu Developer Summit Sponsorship Proposal

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, conferences

[UDS-P](http://uds.ubuntu.com) will be held in Orlando, FL from October 31st – November 4th. While there is a Summit every six months I feel UDS-P is a *vital* event for Ask Ubuntu to have representation in since it will be for the next [Long Term Support](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16366/whats-the-difference-between-a-long-term-support-release-and-a-normal-release/16370#16370) release of Ubuntu. As such, I would like to represent the Ask Ubuntu Community at this event.

## What is the Ubuntu Developer Summit?

The [Ubuntu Developer Summit](http://uds.ubuntu.com/) (UDS) is held twice a year to plan for the next release of Ubuntu. The event pulls together Canonical engineers, community members, partners, ISVs, upstreams and more into an environment focused on discussion and planning. As a whole this is where the next 6 months of development and design are discussed and planned.

## What could I do for Ask Ubuntu while I'm there?

Pending sponsorship, I plan on presenting a lightning talk on Ask Ubuntu to familiarize the teams present about it’s existence. I then plan on holding a multiple sessions throughout the week about how Ubuntu can better integrate Ask Ubuntu into the community at large. As it currently stands [Ubuntu.com doesn’t officially recognize Ask Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/community) as the valued resource it is. Additionally Ask Ubuntu is slowly working it’s way into pieces of Ubuntu Software: Most notably the [Unity](http://unity.ubuntu.com/contact-us/) and [Ubuntu One](https://one.ubuntu.com/help/) webpages as well as the new [Ubiquity Slideshow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wab1t.png) which is visible to all users during the installation process! These integration points are great so far, but I think we could use the next 6 months to take this a step further.

Integration ideas include:

- the Ubuntu Manpages site
- Ubuntu Packages site
- Community Support
- other Ubuntu Service sites
- Talking to line managers at Canonical on how they can use the site better
- Talking to community leaders within Ubuntu on how they can use AU for their team.

I feel having someone like myself from the community working to make these a reality will help push Ask Ubuntu to further success.

## What I'd want to do to promote us there:

Aside from holding talks about the site, I’d like to continue to show that Ask Ubuntu is all about quality content and getting questions answered quickly, completely, and accurately. By actually have a presence in the Summit, to be able to answer questions about the site itself, and direct users to not only ask questions on the site, but also for Ubuntu teams to monitor their respective tags on the site. I can help grow the experts as well as the user base.

## What I would need:

Travel would be relatively cheap for me since I live just a few air hours away; however, I don't think I would be able to afford the week long stay at the hotel at which the event is being held.

So, what do you guys think about this? Do you have any questions or concerns? Personally, I really think this would be a great chance to increase our visibility and grow our relations within the Ubuntu Community. If you think this is a worthwhile pursuit please up-vote or leave comments. If you have any suggestions about what groups I should target during the UDS let me know as well.

Comment: +1 - I can't think of anyone better to attend.

Comment: Sounds good.  I think you ought to update your question with some actions for you (ask for sponsorship? propose sessions?) and for us (upvote you?)

Comment: +1 from me, hope you get to go.

Comment: +1 heck yes from me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Marco has been approved for the Ubuntu Developer Summit in Orlando on October 31st – November 4th. Marco will be working with Jorge Castro to help lead sessions for AskUbuntu where he will be giving away a butt-load of cool AskUbuntu swag.

Marco should be following up with some relevant meta posts reporting about his  experiences in this year's summit.

Incidentally, I am planning on attending the Summit in Orlando on the opening day (Monday). See you there!

Comment: Looking forward to hearing about what happens.