# UDS-P Session Topics

Tags: discussion, conferences, site-promotion

I'll be [attending UDS-P](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1810/ubuntu-developer-summit-sponsorship-proposal) and would like to start a brainstorm of topics that would be good to cover at the summit. The last time we had representation in the form of a session at a UDS was UDS-N which [covered a number of topics in one session](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/631/what-was-discussed-and-what-was-the-outcome-of-the-ask-ubuntu-uds-n-session). This time around I'd like to have another "What is Ask Ubuntu" session to cover the basics and different portions/use cases for the site that aren't that obvious.

Other ideas I had:

- Ask Ubuntu for Power users
- How to integrate with Ask Ubuntu

I have several other ideas, but I'll hold on to them for now as I don't want to stifle community ideas by leading them with my own. What would be effective topics to help promote, interest, and inform Ubuntu Developer Summit goers?

Comment: Oh... now I *really* want to finish my PHP API wrapper. If people are going to integrate with the site, they'll want to play around with the API.

Answer (score 6):

Here's some (some might not be big enough to have a separate session on, so we can just combine the small ones, etc:

- Mining Ask Ubuntu data to improve Ubuntu - this session would be how we can use data.se, anonymous feedback, and other metrics from the site to bring attention to issues. So for example, tech leads and engineering managers need to know how to mine AU data to see what topics are consistently brought up, etc most dupes, which questions are getting the most eyeballs in a tag, etc.

Instead of a "power user" session I would just do:

- How to use Ask Ubuntu More effectively - the audience of UDS is Ubuntu developers and contributors, basically, experts in the field; the kind of people we want participating more often.

.... and lastly, do a 5 minute lightning talk since that lets you address the entire audience at once. Here's [the video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ppt2Og6qp8Y) of myself and Robert doing one last year (go about 4:09 in); a continuation of this might be a good idea, we can sit down in Orlando during the week and bash something out.

Comment: *[trying to contain excitement]* ...and the API! Tell them about the API!

Answer (score 1):

I would thinking of making Ubuntu Developers more involved in AskUbuntu.

For example if you are addressing Kernel developers, you can tell them to keep a watch on `kernel` tag. You can ask them to subscribe to this tag too, such that when a question comes, they can get an email notification.

It would be handy if you can prepare the most used tags and the least answered question tags and get the developers to get more involved in such kind of questions.

Lastly, don't forget to take a minute to sing the song praising the success of AskUbuntu :)

Comment: The kernel folks already do this, they just usually only answer questions about policy as opposed to questions about the kernel itself.

Comment: Any special reason for answering questions only about policy and not about kernel?

Comment: Most of the kernel tags are probably-bug reports, tbh, they only really need to keep an eye on the tag and vote accordingly.

Comment: Ah. Those can be mostly closed and a link added to the bug report (if filed)